# socket.io-client:socket keeps on showing in my browser console

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I tried to use `DEBUG = *` for debugging purposes in javascript socket.io. After debugging, I erased my codes related to that because I don't need it anymore at the moment. But when I try to run my application again, the debugger is still printed in my browser console.

I need help, please. I just want it gone so that I can view my other consoles. What happens when I console something, my browser console gets flooded with socket.io-client:socket and i can't read my console anymore.

Comment: 2 things, have you restarted the server that pushes out your JS..  Is your browser running the cached version..?

Comment: yes I usually use nodemon. I tried to exit and reload nodemon also. Also used node to run my application. I haven't tried to clear my cache. I'll try it now

Comment: omg, thank you so much. my browser console is now clean. thank you so much